# Virtual Keyboard in a chrome kiosk app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, kiosk, on-screen-keyboard

I just created a Chrome Kiosk app following [this doc](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3316168?hl=en&ref_topic=4412375).

Now, I'd like to be able to add a virtual keyboard that shows on/off automatically when (un)focusing on input field.
The app is meant to be used on Windows 10.

Here is what I tried without success:

- Using the built-in Windows 10 virtual keyboard is buggy with Chrome in general. Sometimes the keyboard shows up, and sometimes no. Some users say it is related to Chrome flags, but not sure about that. If it's a good idea to play with chrome flags, how to do so in a kiosk app?
- Using a chrome extension like [Virtual Keyboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-keyboard/pflmllfnnabikmfkkaddkoolinlfninn?hl=en) seems to work (not perfectly though) in a normal Chrome browser, but I can't find out how to embed it in a packaged chrome kiosk app.

How would you do? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameters

--kiosk --load-extension=Extensions/keyboard/

there `Extensions/keyboard/` directory with unpacked extension. You can find it in AppData(.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/pflmllfnnabikmfkkaddkoolinlfninn) dir or download and unzip crx file or from repo https://github.com/xontab/chrome-virtual-keyboard .

PS Not working with iframes